# Can't create new Insights app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.insights

When I try to create a new app in Insights, I get the following message:

```
An active Xamarin Platform license is required to add applications to Insights.
```

Since Xamarin is now free, we no longer pay our accounts. What am I supposed to do? Does this have anything to do with Hockey App?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still need Xamarin Premium account to create Insight app. Once you created the app, you can invite free users to app.

Comment: So pretty much, to use Insights, we have to renew at least one Indie account?